# Can I use a different version of dvisvgm than the one bundled with TeX Live 2023?

Tags: texlive, installing, dvisvgm, texlive-2023

I downloaded `TeX Live 2022` using [these instructions](https://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html), and upgraded to `TeX Live 2023` using [these instructions](https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html). The  `dvisvgm` that ends up getting installed on my system is 3.03. I want to use 3.1. Is there a way I can replace the default `dvisvgm` version, or alternatively set the repository to one which includes the latest `dvisvgm` version?

Comment: Have you tried simply updating your copy of TeX Live? I just checked, and I have `dvisvgm 3.1` installed locally. I update weekly, at least, no idea when they made the switch.

Comment: By way of clarification, Ingmar probably meant something like [what's outlined on this page](https://tug.org/texlive/pkginstall.html), whereby you update to the latest packages.

Comment: According to the [commits in the TL repository](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Build/source/texk/dvisvgm), dvisvgm hasn't been updated to 3.1 there yet. And as far as I know, the TL team updates binary applications like dvisvgm only once a year together with the release of a new TL version. If you're using Linux, there are maybe TL packages coming with your distribution that get updated more frequently.  The latest Windows builds for MiKTeX can be downloaded from the [dvisvgm website](https://dvisvgm.de).

Comment: Yes, I meant using the TeX Live package manager to update all installed packages.

Comment: @Martin: On my Linux box I have a cron script that runs `sudo tlmgr update --all` periodically, that refreshes all the Tex Live packages. There are some updates almost every day. I can confirm to have `dvisvgm 3.1` on my system.

Comment: @Ingmar Thanks for the info. Yes, the non-binary files are updated frequently but the binaries are not. Is your dvisvgm binary located in the TL `bin` directory or do you happen to have another version installed too? At least, I don't get dvisvgm 3.1 through the TL updater (on Linux). The [TL binary repository](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/bin/x86_64-linux) also contains only dvisvgm 3.0.3.

Comment: @Ingmar on windows I have 3.0.3.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Made me look again. Calling `dvisvgm --version` returns 3.0.3 as well, whereas `tlmgr info dvisvgm` gives me version 3.1. You see me confused.

Comment: I used the update instructions two days ago. Running `dvisvgm --version` gives but `tlmgr info dvisvgm` gives 3.1. I think there might be something wrong with it too because I was trying the latex preview system in emacs and the indentation is incorrect which according to others is a sign that something is broken with my DVISVGM version. So I am basically wondering if/how I can delete the texlive version of DVISVGM and replace it with the one from my package manager on linux.